# Gulp suddenly not working: -bash: gulp: command not found

Tags: bash, gulp

I've ran into an error when running Gulp inside a project folder.

I get:

-bash: gulp: command not found

The project was working fine earlier.

Wondering if anyone has had trouble with this?

Thanks

Comment: your `$PATH` has changed I guess.... what does  `echo  $PATH` output ? did you try to reinstalll gulp (`npm install -g gulp`)?

Comment: echo PATH returns /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin

Running npm install returns -bash: npm: command not found

Comment: That's very weird you don't have `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` in your `$PATH` what OS / distro are you running ? did you try opening a new shell ? are you running this command as your usual user ?

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.10.5. I've tried using export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin and export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin in the terminal, and now I'm getting and error of 'Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)' when I run Gulp.

Comment: On Debian, I have something like that `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin`. I'm sorry but mac is really not my cup of tea so I don't  think I can help more...